# Find and replace a string, and to overwrite on the same file using batch script

Tags: batch-file

I'm very new to scripting, and I'm looking for some kind souls here who can help me.

I want to replace the contents ("8888" with "9999") in a file known as Version.dll. I also want to save in the same filename after the script runs. It did not work.

I have to resort to creating a new file "Version1.dll" to make it work, but this is not what I wanted.

May I know if anyone can guide me, to overwrite in the same existing file (Version.dll), after I run the script? Thank you.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
SET "filename1=%C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\Version.dll"
SET "outfile=%C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\Version1.dll"
(
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
SET "line=%%a"
SET "line=!line:8888=9999!"
ECHO !line!
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF`
```

Comment: `move /Y "%outfile%" "%filename1%"`

Comment: Using a temporary file and moving it over the original one (as Aacini suggests) is the best way in terms of performance. Alternatively, you could do this to avoid a temporary file: `for /F "delims=" %%a in ('type "%filename1%" ^& ^> "%filename1%" break') do (set "line=%%a" & set "line=!line:8888=9999!" & >> "%filename1%" echo !line!)`